# Click on <div> to focus <input>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, onclick

I have a series of `input` elements each with a few `<div>` tags separate.
I like to have if where I can `click` on any of the `<div>` and it will `focus` on an `input`.
Is this possible and if so can anyone give ideas on  script?

Comment: It is possible but have you considered using `labels`? I think you shouldn't rely on JavaScript for simple stuff like this when there are dedicated HTML tags for that purpose.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try this with jquery:

```
$('#yourdiv').click(function() {
     $('#yourfield').focus();
});
```

Answer (score 48):

I don't see a reason why you need `JS` to do this when such feature is already provided in `HTML`.

```
<label for="YOURID">The clickable region<label>
<input id="YOURID" type="text" />
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks

Comment: This saved me 8 years later!

Answer (score 16):

Try this :

```
<input id="myInput" />
<div onclick="document.getElementById('myInput').focus(); return false;"></div>
```

Comment: the `div` in this example is not click-able as it has no dimension.

Answer (score 5):

```
$('div').click(function() {
    $(this).find('input[type="text"]').focus();
});​
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/JTnDu/1)

Comment: Like this one over the other solutions as this is more generic and uses unobtrusive JS.

Comment: Thanks for the warm feedback! I liked it too as I wrote it... **:) LOL**

Answer (score 2):

1. using javascript (call .focus() on the input element)
2. using  wrapped around your div (makes only sense if the div *is* the label)

Answer (score 1):

1. USING HTML ("**for**") :

   HTML provides this functionality.
   Using "**for**" "**id**" you can easily achieve it.

> ```
>  <label for="idname">Click Here to Reach Input<label>
>  <input id="idname" type="text">
> ```

2. USING jQuery ("**focus**")

> $(".classname").click(function(){
>
> > $("input").**focus**(); })