# Click anywhere on a div to trigger an input

Tags: javascript, jquery, uploadcare

I am trying to make it so when you click on a particular div, it triggers an input button to open up the uploadcare widget.

Here is the HTML in question

```
<div class="col-md-6 image-preview-single">
<img src="" alt="" class="img-responsive card-shadow hidden">
    <div id="logo-upload" class="add-new-short add-new-home-realtor card-shadow-mini btn-file uploader-homicity" style="display:block;text-decoration:none; cursor: pointer;">
        <i class="fa fa-photo"/>
        <input type="hidden" role="uploadcare-uploader" name="logo" data-upload-url-base="" data-images-only="true" data-crop="150x150" data-clearable="true" id="logo-input">
            <div class="uploadcare-widget uploadcare-widget-option-clearable uploadcare-widget-status-ready" data-status="ready">
                <div class="uploadcare-widget-dragndrop-area">
                    Drop a file here
                </div>
                <div class="uploadcare-widget-status uploadcare-widget-circle uploadcare-widget-circle--canvas">
                    <canvas width="56" height="56"/>
                </div>
                <div class="uploadcare-widget-text">
                </div>
                <div tabindex="0" role="button" class="uploadcare-widget-button uploadcare-widget-button-open">Choose an image</div>
                <div tabindex="0" role="button" class="uploadcare-widget-button uploadcare-widget-button-cancel">Cancel</div>
                <div tabindex="0" role="button" class="uploadcare-widget-button uploadcare-widget-button-remove">Remove</div>
            </div> 
    </div>
```

And Jquery in question

```
$( '#logo-upload' ).on( 'click', function() {
    $('input#logo-input').click();
});
```

And this is the console error

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at RegExp.exec (<anonymous>)
    at n.fn.init (jquery.min.js:2)
    at n (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (uploadcare.js:72)
    at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLDivElement.r.handle (jquery.min.js:3)
    at Object.trigger (jquery.min.js:4)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:4)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at n.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js:2)
```

What am I missing on this?

Thanks

Comment: Since element is nested inside, you've to prevent the bubbling up the event.

Comment: [How to `focus()` an `<input>` on click of a `<div>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10164015/click-on-div-to-focus-input)?

Comment: Have you debugged? It's on a loop.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add also this event on input click:

```
$('input#logo-input').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    ...your code
});
```

You need to [stop propagation](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) because you create infinite loop.
When you trigger click on input, this input is inside `logo-upload` div and click on input is propagate to this container and this create infinite loop.

Comment: `preventDefault` is harmless but unnecessary here; `stopPropagation` is doing the job.

Comment: Yes @DanielBeck `preventDefault` is not important here, but `stopPropagation` is the key to stop infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

1. Use a `<label>` to activate the input with just html:

   `<label for="yourId">Click here<label>
   <input id="yourId" type="text" />`
2. Use `focus()` instead of `click()` with `stopPropagation()` and `stopPropagation()`:

   `$('#logo-upload' ).on( 'click', function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          e.stopPropagation();
          $('input#logo-input').focus();
   });`

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

so you want to open Uploadcare **dialog**, not a **widget**.

First, remove all the widget's HTML code from your page, it is added by library and should be in served document.
Second, use the following code

```
$('#logo-upload').on('click', function() {
    uploadcare.Widget(input_selector).openDialog();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

just do this.

```
var inputSP = input.click(function (e) { e.stopPropagation(); });

dropper.on('click', function (e) {
   e.stopPropagation();   
    // here we first stop propagation then make a call to click event 
   inputSP; 
   input.click();
});
```